# insert into with select statement sql server

Tags: sql

I created an procedure to insert data from another table as follows:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STP_addCompanySection;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE STP_addCompanySection ()
BEGIN

insert into companySection(categoryName,description) 
select categoryName,description from BusinessCat where deleted='0';

END \g
DELIMITER ;
```

Can I add another column on insert like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STP_addCompanySection;


DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE STP_addCompanySection (
IN inCompanyId int
)
BEGIN

insert into companySection(categoryName,description,comId) 
(select categoryName,description from BusinessCat where deleted='0' ,inCompanyId);
select LAST_INSERT_ID() id;

END \g
DELIMITER ;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
insert into companySection(categoryName,description,comId) 
(select categoryName,description, inCompanyId 
 from BusinessCat 
 where deleted='0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
insert into companySection(categoryName,description,comId) 
select categoryName,description,inCompanyId from BusinessCat where deleted='0';
select LAST_INSERT_ID() id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other users are missing the question.  Dynamic SQL will probably be your solution.  Your input parameter value will be a string of whatever column you want to inject.  Your stored procedure will contain:

```
DECLARE @MySQL VARCHAR(MAX);

@MySQL = 'insert into companySection(categoryName,description,comId)
(select categoryName,description ' + ,inCompanyId + ' from BusinessCat where     deleted='0' );' 

EXEC (@MySQL);
```

Note that this is very vulnerable to SQL injection and read up on the topic if you are not aware of it.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, add it to the select list:

```
insert into companySection(categoryName,description,comId) 
(select categoryName,description, inCompanyID from BusinessCat where deleted='0');
```

Comment: No, we were just both answering at the same time.